Make Git remind me to use switch / restore instead of checkout
I want to teach my hands to use the new git switch and git restore instead of using git checkout for everything (see What's the difference between 'git switch' and 'git checkout' <branch>?). What would be a good way to configure my Linux terminal (Bash) to remind me, or even complain, whenever I use the old style?
I know that one way would be to write a bash function, but I was wondering if there are also better / more standard ways, such as a configuration in Git to not use deprecated commands. In that sense, not necessarily a duplicate question.

What an odd close-vote. If it were clear that the answer to this question is "you need to wrap 'git' in a function and that calls it within as a command", this detail would have surely appeared in the title or content of the question.

Alternative answers would have been "you need to configure something in Git" or "you can install this additional package that does it for you". I don't think this is directly a duplicate.

yeah, or create a git command of your own in a different path which takes precedence

.bashrc function
git() {
    if [[ "$1" = checkout ]]; then
        echo 'Use switch or restore!' >&2
        return 1
    fi

    command git "$@"
}


@Guildenstern: It works well enough in practice.

This would still mean that if I call a valid checkout command, I still get the warning, right? (which is fine, as most of the time I don't need to explicitly call checkout)

@MakisH: If I understand your question, yes. If you find that that’s getting in the way before you retrain your muscle memory, you make the warning more specific for -b/single arguments/whatever’s ingrained (&& ("$2" = -b || $# -eq 2)… restore gets more complicated). Or take out the return 1 so the command still runs, but that might be less effective, since it doesn’t force you to correct yourself.
